# Fatal error: Class 'PHPExcel_IOFactory' not found

Tags: php, phpexcel

I'm trying to read some excel cells and insert their contents into a table but I get the error on the title. I have extracted the PHPExcel folder in the same place as the php files I want to use them on. The IOFactory.php is inside, checked that too, but it just doesn't seem to work even though it worked fine with another project. I'm thinking I've done some dumb mistake in the code as usual so here it is

```
<?php 
$connect = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "productionline");
include ("PHPExcel/IOFactory.php");
$objPHPExcel = PHPExcel_IOFactory::load('1093.xls');
$orderid = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, $worksheet->getCellByColumnAndRow(S, 1)->getValue());
$customer = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, $worksheet->getCellByColumnAndRow(V, 2)->getValue());
$productname = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, $worksheet->getCellByColumnAndRow(AC, 2)->getValue());
$orderdate = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, $worksheet->getCellByColumnAndRow(D, 2)->getValue());
$deliverydate = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, $worksheet->getCellByColumnAndRow(I, 2)->getValue());
$sql = "INSERT INTO orders(OrderID, Customer, ProductName, OrderDate, DeliveryDate) VALUES ('".$orderid."', '".$customer."', '".$productname."', '".$orderdate."', '".$deliverydate."')";
mysqli_query($connect, $sql);
header('Location: home.php');
?>
```

Comment: The path to IOFactory might be incorrect and you've disabled errors. Verify it exists with `file_exists` or use `require` instead to make sure your site doesn't output if it can't find the included file.

Comment: I would recommend loading such libraries with an autoloader. `composer` should help you.

Answer (score 0):

The examples use `require_once '../Build/PHPExcel.phar';` rather than `IOFactory` directly.

Have you tried their examples by including the `.phar` instead as that seems to be the documented method.